# Salesforce Code Analyser

Tags: apex, managed-package, security-scanner

Im having trouble identifying what is wrong with the below method, the salesforce code analyser if flagging it as a InternalExecutionError with the below error:

Is anyone able to explain what the issue is here? the code can deploy to my scratch org with no problems.

> Graph Engine identified your source and sink, but you must manually verify that you have a sanitizer in this path. Then, add an engine directive to skip the path. Next, create a Github issue for the Code Analyzer team that includes the error and stack trace. After we fix this issue, check the Code Analyzer release notes for more info.
>
> Error and stacktrace: NoSuchElementException: No value present: java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:148);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.ObjectBasedCheckUtil.isCrudCheckExpected(ObjectBasedCheckUtil.java:67);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.isCheckLevelValid(SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.java:199);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.convert(SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.java:174);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.checkForValidation(SchemaBasedValidationAnalyzer.java:77);com.salesforce.rules.fls.apex.operations.FlsValidationCentral.checkSchemaBasedFlsValidation(FlsValidationCentral.java:71)

My method is:

```
global static Database.DeleteResult flsDelete (sObject flsSObject) {
    if(null != flsSObject){
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult flsDescribe = flsSObject.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
    
        if (flsDescribe.isDeletable()) {
            return Database.delete(flsSObject);
        }
        else {
            throw new CPQCustomException('DatabaseFLS.flsDelete: Error deleting [' + flsDescribe.getName() + '] object. Check that the user has the required rights.');
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the Code Analyzer itself has an issue and is giving you instructions on how to report it. Maybe something's wrong with your code, maybe not, but it made Code Analyzer crash, so congratulations on that ;-)

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that `if(null != flsSObject){` may be the problem. Yoda conditions are an unusual coding style in Apex, and it's possible the rule engine hasn't accounted for that. Try `if(flsObject != null){` and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, please ask if the method is necessary at all. You can run deletions in user context and your code will run faster - you have a describe call, which isn't memoized and will happen once per record. It isn't bulkified. There's no dml, but there is a describe.